# Looking for the simplest way to create the following attenuated rectangular spiral

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to learn how to create a rectangular spiral without having to hard code the calculation as follows. Could you make it more elegant with looping and/or conditional constructs?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\L{5}
\def\r{.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) --
                ++(\L,0) --
                ++(0,-\L*\r) --
                ++(-\L*\r*\r,0) --
                ++(0,\L*\r*\r*\r) --
                ++(\L*\r*\r*\r*\r,0) --
                ++(0,-\L*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r) --
                ++(-\L*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r,0) --
                ++(0,\L*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r*\r) 
                ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit:

You can choose any number of iteration `N` that I can change later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\L{5}
\def\r{.9}
\def\N{50}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick] (0,0) 
    foreach \k in {0,...,\N}
    {
      -- ++ ([rotate=-90*\k,scale=\r^\k]\L,0)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The line `-- ++ ([rotate=-90*\k,scale=\r^\k]\L,0)` does the same as the polar notation `-- ++ (-90*\k : \r^\k * \L)`.
The keys `rotate` and `scale` are documented in the manual.
The syntax used here `([<transformations>]<coordinate>)`
applies those keys to the coordinate it is in.
It is a bit like a tikz `scope`, only more localized. I wrote it this way because this construct was in my mind after the previous answer, but it is not the most simple here.

Comment: The transformation `[rotate=...,scale=...]` is applied to the whole vector `(\L,0)`, understood in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @SinglePackAbs No, that doesn't make sense. You may be interested in `yscale` though ?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs That is what inline scopes are for.

Answer (score 8):

Turns out, OP wanted a geometric spiral (and only said so one hour after I had answered...)

I think it must not be very hard to do, but this is not the question this answer is about.

## Edit spiralling inwards

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\N{9}
  \def\r{.5}

  \coordinate (a) at (10,6) ;
  \draw[thick] (a) {[shift={(\N*\r,-\N*\r)}]
    foreach \k [evaluate=\k as \kk using \N-\k] in {0,1,...,\N} 
      {
        |- + ([,scale=\r] \kk,\kk) 
        |- + ([,scale=\r] -\kk,-\kk) 
      }
      node[draw,blue,very thick,fill=white] {end}
    } ;
  \node [draw,red,very thick,fill=white] (a) at (10,6) {weStartFromHere} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Original spiralling outwards

Like this ?

- The blue (left) version is for spiralling from `(0,0)`.
- The red (right) version is portable from any initial point.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\N{9}
  \def\r{.5}
  \draw[blue] (0,0) foreach\k in {1,...,\N} {[scale=\r] |- (\k,-\k) |- (-\k,\k) } ;
  \draw[red] (10,0) foreach\k in {1,...,\N} {|- + ([scale=\r]\k,-\k) |- + ([scale=\r]-\k,\k) } ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you like it better starting from the other end ?

Comment: @SinglePackAbs Yeah, alright, I probably should have been more careful in reading your code, but it would have been useful if you corrected earlier...